# Editing Word Styles in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am looking to edit Word Styles on a document using VB.Net Code.
This is so that any document created by my program anywhere will have the correct styles.

I have found code that allows me to edit font, colour, size, etc. but I am stuck on two parts.

Some of the styles have a border and when look at the border in Word it gives the following breakdown

```
Border:
Bottom: (Single solid line, Accent 1, 0.5 pt Line width, From text: 4 pt Border spacing:)
```

I've got everything apart from the distance from text.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/borders-distancefrombottom-property-word says that there should be a property for that but when I attempt to use it in my code I get ".DistanceFromBottom is not a member of Border"

Some of the styles also have indents and I cannot work out how to apply these. Word gives the breakdown as such :

```
Indent:
Left:  1.27 cm
Right:  1.65 cm, Space
Before:  10 pt
After:  14 pt
```

I cannot find any library or coding that allows me to put in an indent as part of a style but you can when making the style in Word. It seems odd that Microsoft would allow you to manipulate almost everything else about a style except indents.

So far the code I have for one on the styles is :

```
With doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleIntenseQuote)

        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Cambria"
        .Font.Color = RGB(79, 129, 189)

        With .Borders(WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
            .Color = RGB(79, 129, 189)
            .LineWidth = WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth050pt
        End With

    End With
```

If anyone needs anything clarifying then please ask away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the borders: if you look carefully at the link you provide you'll see it's specific to *Page* borders, not borders around text. This kind of border cannot be part of a style.

If you're creating a style to format entire paragraphs (which is the case when you specify Indent) you probably shouldn't be using a Linked style. Better a Paragraph or ParagarphOnly style. Linked style can be extremely confusing.

Indents are part of the Paragraph formatting. `Before` and `After` do not apply to indents; they're the vertical spacing between paragraphs.

There are three kinds of indent: LeftIndent, RightIndent and FirstLineIndent. Left affects all lines from the left margin; right all lines from the right margin; FirstLine sets how the first line differs from the standard setting (LeftIndent) *relative* to the left margin.

For an indent such as one sees in many books (the first line is further to the right):

```
Dim doc As Word.Document = ActiveDocument
Dim styl as Word.Style = doc.styles.Add("IndentStyle", wdStyleTypeParagraphOnly)
styl.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 7
```

For a hanging indent (all lines except the first are indented - used most often with bullets or numbering):

```
Dim doc As Word.Document = ActiveDocument
Dim styl as Word.Style = doc.styles.Add("IndentStyle", wdStyleTypeParagraphOnly)
styl.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 7
styl.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = -7 'Puts it at 0 relative to margin
```

Tip for figuring out what objects, properties and methods you need: record a macro in Word while doing something (creating or modifying a style) then look at the result.

Comment: Hi Cindy. Thanks for the advice and the .ParagraphFormat property was exactly what I was looking for. I've tried using recording a Macro to achieve what I want, but it gives me the code in VBA which is not always compatible with code in VB.net and I sometimes have trouble finding the correct change in coding.

Comment: @MattBartlett I completely understand :-) Funny, how things come in groups - another .NET dev discovered ParagraphFormat yesterday, but tried to populate it, then assign it to the Style, which just doesn't work in VBA, but usually does in .NET.

Comment: Now I'm banging my head against a Mutillevel List. The styles are all in and fine and I have code that applies the number to the styles being use. Problem is that none of the lower levels refer to the higher levels for the numbering. Do you have experience with Multilevel numbering in VB.Net?

Comment: Ask a new question :-) But first play around with multi-level numbering in Word - those last items in the dropdown about defining new. Click "More" in that dialog box and explore how things work. There's a setting for including previous levels. When you have working record a macro and study the result (it's verbose).

Answer (score 0):

Easier approach is to limit the users of your program to using particular templates only. You can then define (and limit) the styles in use in those templates.

Much easier to define a style in a template than in VBA.

Where an external document is used, you can apply your own template to it. If you need further cleaning up/checking, you can use [the advice Cindy Meister provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516066/editing-word-styles-in-vb-net/49517180#49517180).